# Create multiple instances of the same class with Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Sorry if it's a trivial question, I am new to Guice.
Let's say I have the following class:

```
public class MyClass {
     @Inject
     public MyClass(final MyDependency myDependency) {
          this.name = myDependency.getName();
     }

     public String getName() {
          this.name;
     }
}
```

Then somewhere else I want to do:

```
public class SomeOtherClass {
    public void test() {
        MyClass instanceFoo = injector.getInstance(MyClass.class);
        MyClass instanceBar = injector.getInstance(MyClass.class);

        assertTrue("foo", instanceFoo.getName());
        assertTrue("bar", instanceBar.getName());
    }
}
```

I would like to have two instances of "MyClass", one which has a name of "foo" and one with a name of "bar" (i.e. each of them has a different instance of it's dependency as well). How can I add those 2 instances to my injector, and how can I retrieve each of them with "injector.getInstance"?

I don't want to create a subclass of "MyClass" for each possible dependency.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question, as in the title, has a simpler solution: If you want an arbitrary number of instances of MyClass or MyDependency, you can inject a `Provider<MyClass>` or `Provider<MyDependency>`. This is true whether or not you've actually bound a Provider in a Module; for any T available in the graph Guice can actually inject either `T` or `Provider<T>`. (These correspond to `Injector.getInstance` and `Injector.getProvider` respectively.)

As in the body of the question, there are two pieces: Making more than one injectable `Key` for the same `Class`, and setting up the instances the way you want with different names and injected dependencies.

### Keys and Binding Annotations

Guice identifies bindings using a `Key`, which is a fully-qualified class (like `MyClass` or `List<MyClass>`) combined with an optional "binding annotation". This is an annotation that is itself annotated with `BindingAnnotation` or `javax.inject.Qualifier`; you can create your own, or use the built in one called `@Named` that takes a String (so `@Named("foo")` is different from `@Named("bar")`).

Most of the time, you can get by without using Key directly: Use `annotatedWith` in your `bind` calls or add the annotation onto `@Provides` methods, and request them by putting the annotation onto constructor parameters or @Inject-annotated fields. However, you can still use `getInstance` and `getProvider` by creating a Key manually, using the static methods on Key. (For complicated cases, use TypeLiteral or `Names.named`; see their docs for details.)

### Setting up instances

Now that you know how to inject `@Named("foo") MyClass` or `@Foo MyClass`, how do you provide them? Depending on your needs, I'd choose one of three options: binding `toInstance`, using a `@Provides` method, or creating an "assisted injection" factory.

- If your MyClass instances don't need injection themselves, and you don't mutate or manipulate instance state, you could just prepare the instances named as needed and then `bind` them with `toInstance`.
- You could also write a `@Provides @Named("foo") MyClass` method that takes a `MyClass` parameter (which Guice supplies through the injector), sets the name, and returns the instance. This is a low-overhead alternative to writing a Provider class or instance, and will get you a fresh instance rather than the sharing that a `toInstance` binding would imply.
- If you really want the `name` to be a part of your class's constructor parameters, perhaps to keep the instance immutable, you can use "Assisted Injection" to tell Guice which parameters you supply yourself and which come from the Guice injector. This would allow you to inject a `MyClass.Factory` and call `myClassFactory.create("foo")`, which you could do directly in your consuming classes, or using the `@Provides` technique above. The details are a little beyond the scope of the question, but look up "Assisted Injection" for details on syntax and on adding the appropriate JAR.